# Suggestion: Ignore dashes (-) in the tag search / drop down box when asking a question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Could the dash (-) be ignored in the tab completion dialog?

So for example, if someone typed in `sqlserver` as a tag, they would see tags of the format `sql-server*` in the results - currently they only see tags of the format `sqlserver*`

The reason that I suggest this is that although the convention is to use the dash as a separator in tags (for example `sql-server` or `visual-studio`), its not always immediately obvious where the seperator should go.  This inevitably ends up with a small percentage of people tagging a question as being `sqlserver` rather than `sql-server`.

Also, I'm suggesting this on the assumption that this would be easy to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a great idea, especially since the auto-completion box tells you which version of the tag is the more often used one:

[image]