# Dashes don't work in the new Tag Selector

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-declined, tag-autocomplete

This is related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39513/suggestion-ignore-dashes-in-the-tag-search-drop-down-box-when-asking-a-que), about ignoring dashes in the tag search.

How about we ignore them when they're not entered, so that tags will be found with dashes or not, **BUT** lets allow if the user puts a dash in, to bring up just the tags with a dash.

Here's an image showing that `stl-` doesn't show all the tags that start/contain that phrase, it completely ignores the dash, so the user doesn't see the other valid `stl-` tags:

[image: Tag Selector Broken Dash Example]

I hope I explained it so you understand, I think the dash should be ignored in one direction but not the other.

NOTE:  Right now it means for instance that I cannot bring up a list of all tags that start with `stl-`, I have to type each letter and see what's there, like `stl-a`.

Comment: I agree that this should be changed.  Other punctuation should be ignored, but not hyphens.

Answer (score 4):

A large reason for duplicate tags is one person creating it *with* a dash, the other one *without*; say [multi-threading](/questions/tagged/multi-threading) vs. [multithreading](/questions/tagged/multithreading) or [asp.net-mvc-3](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-3) vs. [asp.net-mvc3](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc3). That is why the dashes are ignored when searching for a tag (not only in the tag editor, but also e.g. in the search box on the [tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags). We *want* people to see the alternatives.

This isn't related to the new tag editor, by the way – this happened just as well in the old autocomplete version; nothing has changed there.

Comment: yes, it's the behavior on the tags page also, but there's more possible selections there so it doesn't matter.  Now people will just not realize that there is a tag out there, and recreate it.  And for those of use who know the tag is there, it takes that extra nanosecond of time. (why oh why do I only have a 5-minute comment edit time)